# php form not sending info via email about 30% of time

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm getting a 'this message has no content' error about 30% of the time a visitor completes the form and cannot isolate the problem. The php for sending the email is below with addresses anonymized. Any ideas?

I've tried to find an answer in the forums to no avail so far. Thanks for your help!

```
<?php

    $fromAddress = 'x@www.com';
    $subject = 'Resources - White Paper Download - '.$_POST['WhitePaper'];

    $message .= "\r\n";

    foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    $message .= $name . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
    }

    $to       = 'y@www.com';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $fromAddress . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $fromAddress . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: z@www.com, <t@www.com>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "mail sent";
?>
```

Comment: Just a note, if $fromAddress is taken from user input, make sure to strip any newline characters from it, otherwise you are vulnerable to email injection.

Comment: seeing the code of the form could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing consistent that you can spot (ie do certain links always fail, or do they work some of the time?) then all I can suggest is that you add as much logging into the code as you can, and see if there's a pattern.

Create a log file, and every time your mailing code is called, write the details of the email to it, as well as the response from the server; then check and see if you can replicate the problem when you see the error show up.

The only thing I can see that might be causing it is if $_POST is empty - I assume that you're always calling the script in the same way, and you're never linking to it with _GET parameters set?